How to check if current order is a switch order or a parent order in a subscription?
I have a few lines of code that look through an order and perform an action IF the order includes a particular subscription product (id 12496) and the total is more than 0.
function get_product_data( $customer_data, $order ) {

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {

        if ( 12496 === $item->get_product_id() && ($order->get_total() > '0') ) {
            $customer_data['journey_sub_variation'] = $item['variation_id'];
        }
    }

    return $customer_data;

}
add_filter( 'wpf_woocommerce_customer_data', 'get_product_data', 10, 2 );

This all works ok, but it's not exactly what I wanted. The reason I added the " > '0' " condition is because I want the script to ignore orders that are "Switch Orders". But not all nill orders are necessarily switch orders. Parent orders in our subs are often 0 (we use free trials) so it's not the correct solution.
What I would really like to do is perform the action IF the order includes that subscription product (id 12496) and it is not a Switch order.
Alternatively, we could check if the order in question is a parent order and so perform the action even if the total is 0.
Hope that makes sense.
I have tried playing with it for a few hours now, but can't get anything to work.
Any ideas?

LoicTheAztec's code did not work for me but was of great help in getting to a working solution. Here it is:
function get_product_data( $customer_data, $order ) {

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {

        if ( 12496 === $item->get_product_id() && (($order->get_total() > '0') || wcs_order_contains_subscription( $order, 'parent' )) ) {
            $customer_data['journey_sub_variation'] = $item['variation_id'];
        }
    }

    return $customer_data;

}
add_filter( 'wpf_woocommerce_customer_data', 'get_product_data', 10, 2 );

Thanks again LoicTheAztec

To check if a given order was used to switch a subscription via checkout, you can use wcs_order_contains_subscription() conditional function like:
function get_product_data( $customer_data, $order ) {
    // Exit if it is a switched subscription order
    if ( wcs_order_contains_subscription( $order, 'switch' ) ) {
        return $customer_data;
    }

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        if ( 12496 === $item->get_product_id() ) {
            $customer_data['journey_sub_variation'] = $item['variation_id'];
        }
    }
    return $customer_data;
}
add_filter( 'wpf_woocommerce_customer_data', 'get_product_data', 10, 2 );

It should work.
The 2nd argument from wcs_order_contains_subscription() conditional function is the order type (array|string) (optional). It can include 'parent', 'renewal', 'resubscribe' and/or 'switch'. Defaults value is set to 'parent'.

Addition:
To check if an order is the main order (not a child order), you can use WC_Order get_parent_id() method like:
if ( ! $order->get_parent_id() ) {
    // It is a main root order
} else {
    // It is a child order
}


Hi there. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. The code you provided did not work for some reason, but I kept playing with that function and eventually got something working. I will add it below. Thanks again.
